# Using Cache for memorizing users sessions?

Tags: session, cakephp, caching

I'm working on a project where admins can delete the accounts of other users.

Recently I bumped into a problem: what happens when an admin deletes an account while the user is logged in? Someone suggested that the users data should be stored in the Cache system so it can be deleted at any time, but that doesn't sound right to me.

My idea is that the users authentication data should always be stored in the session, but I can't find any arguments on why using the Cache system in this way is a bad idea. So, what is the best practice for handling a situation such as this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in almost all cases, you'd want to immediately disconnect the logged-in user. You probably have your user information in a database and the authentication information in a session. This is fine. I'd simply have the delete process consist of two steps:

1. Remove the user from the database. This will prevent new logins. (Edit: Or better, toggle an `active` flag so that you maintain any existing user_id associations, and they can't re-register.)
2. Remove all existing sessions for the user. This will essentially disconnect the user on their next page refresh.

Comment: I agree with the first part, but how about step #2? I don't think it is possible to delete the user session without checking the database at every refresh. That's why the "Cache instead of sessions" idea was suggested, since the cache is at the application level and can be accessed by all users.

Comment: "I don't think it is possible to delete the user session without checking the database at every refresh." I don't understand what you mean by this. You should be able to arbitrarily delete any session data you want.

Comment: @alex.ac you can delete the user session at the moment of deleting his account, in the delete action. What I am not sure is how can you delete the user session. Like this?  `$this->Session->delete('Auth.User.id')`

Comment: Alex, how could you destroy another user session? If you do `$this->Session->delete('Auth.User.id')` you only destroys the session of the user who is deleting another user.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Cake to answer this within the context of that framework, but if your storage backend is (for example) a database, you can simply delete from the sessions table for that userid.

Comment: The missing piece is tying the user account to a PHP session ID. If every time the user logs in your store their session ID in the users table you can create that link. Then when you delete that user account, delete that session file. I'm not sure that's kosher, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you all your helping :) Steve, I agree with your last comment. dmertl and Alex, you're right, storing the session ID in the database seems like a good idea. It doesn't even have to be a session ID, it can be an access token, but in general I think it's a better practice than storing this type of info in the Cache.

Comment: Don't store the session id (or any access token) in the user table, that breaks concurrent logins. I recommend storing the user id in the session. Whatever your session storage mechanism happens to be, this will allow you to query (and then delete) all sessions for that user. If you're using database-backed session storage then you just have: `DELETE FROM session WHERE user_id = $user_id;`